# Primordial flunctuation gave rise to cosmic structures?

Tags: big-bang, cosmological-inflation

I'm not a physicist, not even a physics student. I'm just reading Lawrence Krauss's book *A Universe From Nothing* and I got stuck understanding a concept. In his book, Lawrence says:

> Quantum fluctuations, which otherwise would have been completely invisible, get frozen by inflation and emerge afterward as density fluctuations that produce everything we can see.

I'm a bit confused here, didn't big bang already created all the raw materials needed to produce "everything we can see"? How can quantum fluctuation after inflation affect stars/galaxies/clusters formation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read this book, so I'm guessing. The fluctuations did not create any raw material for what we see. The material was there already. The fluctuations were just regions where the material was denser, so it started to gravitationally colapse to form clusters of galaxies.

In this sense the fluctuations affected the galaxy formation. The inflation just increased these fluctuations to macroscopic size.

Comment: Thanks for you asnwer. I still don't get it. isn't quantum flunctuation temporary change in energy which leads to virtual particles creation? What do you mean by saying that inflation increased flunctuation to macroscopic level? Sorry if I ask something foolish, as I said, I'm just curious amateur :)

Comment: @Davita Quantum fluctuations are in fact much more complex subject. To better understand this you would need to understand at least basics of quantum field theory. It is not just about some virtual particles. In very simplified terms: fluctuations can be interpreted also as uncertainty in particle density. When inflated, these uncertainties became real regions with real particle density differences.